# Facing issue in Shell while executing query on remote postgres database

Tags: shell

I am running one shell script on my App server which will go on another machine where Postgres database is installed. It will execute query and return couple of IDs and store into variables. Please find below my shell script.

```
ssh root@<Remote_HOST> 'bash -s'<< EOF 
projectid=`/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/psql $DB_NAME -U $DB_USER -h $DB_HOST -t -c "select projectid from projects where project_Name='$projectName';"`
scenarioid=`/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/psql $DB_NAME -U $DB_USER -h $DB_HOST -t -c  "select scenarioid from scenarios where scenario='$scenario' and projectid='$projectid';"`
EOF
echo $projectid
```

If i execute Shell, i get following error :
    /root/test/data.sh: line 62: /usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/psql: No such file or directory
    /root/test/data.sh: line 62: /usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/psql: No such file or directory

But on machine where database is installed, if i execute same query, i get proper results. So i am not sure what is wrong,  query is fine and directory is present. Even after SSH to remote host, if i do ls or pwd, i am getting proper output. I have already exported database password, so database login without password is already working fine.

Can some please tell me what am i missing here?

Comment: look at this; http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21587/postgresql-is-running-locally-but-i-cannot-connect-why

Comment: Thank you. I got idea referring some details mentioned over the link. I am trying few things as mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i was able to resolve my issue by making changes in Shell

```
projectid=$(ssh root@<Remote_HOST> << EOF 
/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/psql $DB_NAME -U $DB_USER -h $DB_HOST -t -c "select projectid from projects where project_Name='$projectName';"
EOF)
scenarioid=$(ssh root@<Remote_HOST> << EOF
/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/psql $DB_NAME -U $DB_USER -h $DB_HOST -t -c "select scenarioid from scenarios where scenario='$scenario' and     projectid='$projectid';"
EOF)
echo "$projectid : $scenarioid"
```